# Why is my Android Intent not working?

Tags: java, android, fragment

```
public class BlankFragmentTab1 extends Fragment {

  public BlankFragmentTab1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment_tab1, container, false);

    Button bsave = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    bsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });

    return rootView;
  }
}
```

It is not working.

Comment: Can you provide error logs?

Comment: Has `Main2Activity` been defined as an activity in the Manifest? Do you get any error messages (you should if `Main2Activity` is not defined in the activity)? If so then edit your post to include the stack trace/log from the log (unsure then search for android stack trace and you should find something to help you locate it). The issue may be in `Main2Activity`, perhaps edit your post to include that, perhaps temporarily simplify it just to see if it's getting started.

Comment: please provide your logcat

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with `getActivity().startActivity(myIntent)`